CA Endevor Mainframe - is there any option available for Freeze the Package in Endevor like Changeman
CA Endevor Mainframe - is there any option available for Freeze the Package in Endevor like Changeman
I know the we can do the following steps in PACKAGE such as CAST, REVIEW, Approve, Execute the Packages but i forgot whether we have option for Freeze the package in Endevor
Freeze can we done in Endevor and how ? i dont remember any option in Endevor tool

Freezing the elements being cast in a package is done automatically on cast, provided the Freeze function has been activated by the Endevor administrator:
https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-mainframe-software/devops/ca-endevor-software-change-manager/19-0/using/ispf-interface-for-development-tasks/package-element-actions/element-locking-for-packages.html
Hope this helps.
